# How to create a custom testsuite and run testsuite for a django app using mongodatabase

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have a django app structure

```
/myapp
/myapp/obj1/..
/myapp/obj1/views.py
/myapp/obj1/forms.py
/myapp/obj2/..
/myapp/obj2/views.py
/myapp/obj2/forms.py
/myapp/tests/..
/myapp/tests/__init__.py
/myapp/tests/obj1.py
/myapp/tests/obj2.py
```

I can run each test file under tests directory of django app using

```
python manage.py test myapp.tests.obj1.py
```

Can u help me to create a testsuite and run testsuite of all testcases as report file in django?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what by: "as report file." The default behavior in Django when you issue `python manage.py test` is to find all the test cases in your test files 
and automatically build a test suite out of those test cases, and run them.
More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/overview/).